# Am I using "attempting" correctly?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-choice

I want to say:

> It is `attempting to` drink sea water when you feel extremely thirsty,
>   but doing it will only kill you.

Here by saying `attempting to` I would like to emphasize the feeling that "can not **refuse** to try"... But I am not sure by using `attempting` is the right word or right way.

Comment: Using `attempting` in this way makes it seem you are reffering to another organism (it). Better is using something alike to what you said and taking out _"is"_: _It seems alright to drink sea water when you are extremely thirsty, but doing it will only kill you._

Comment: @viktorahlström I would like to emphasize the feeling that "can not refuse to try".

Comment: @Denoising, do you mean "tempting"?

Comment: @shin...yea you are absolutely right....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not express what you want to say, I'm afraid.  I think you are looking to say that drinking sea water *might seem appropriate* or *might seem acceptable* (or as @viktorahlström suggests, *seems alright*).

The second clause doesn't sound right.  Replace *it* with *so*, to end up with

> Drinking sea water might seem acceptable when you feel extremely thirsty, but doing so will only kill you.

(we'll leave out the accuracy of the entire statement as off-topic).

Based on the edit, you can emphasize what you want to say by

> Drinking sea water can be *impossible to resist* when you feel ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry my first post is not clear. I just edit it. Please have a look.

Comment: What about "It may be seemed fine to drink sea water when you are extremely thirsty, but that **would** kill you ". I mean use would rather will.  We use would to indicate certain consequences of an action, consider: "It would explode if you keep heating it" why, you all, have used will rather would ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @Victor. I just realize I confused the word "attempting" and "tempting"... But your answer is really good. I accept it!

Comment: Ah...  It didn't occur to me to reduce *attempting* to *tempting*.  You're right, "It is tempting ..." makes more sense.